# erase part moving image

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to clear the canvas (html5)of only 1 element only ? I have a moving image on a canvas  and when I erase the image the background color goes as well. Is there a way to just remove the image and not the whole background. My background is just a simple color but in the future it will be more complicated.

This is also tricky because there is no way to get image x,y pos from a property.

```
  ClassLoadImages.prototype.m_move = function(){
     this.x=++img1_x;
     this.y=++img1_y; 
     //img1_x++;
   //img1_y++;
  // alert(img.x);
      ctx.drawImage(img.imgElement,  this.x,   this.y);
     // ctx.fillText("finished loading " ,10,40);
  };


 function doGameLoop() {

    ctx.clearRect(0,0,600,400);
    img.m_move();
     if (img.x>30)
     {
          clearInterval(gameLoop);

     }
 }




  var img= new ClassLoadImages('images/image4.jpg');
 gameLoop = setInterval(doGameLoop, 100);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer is no.  A canvas is a flat bitmap, not a layered collection of objects. Once you draw to it you lose the background behind the thing you draw.

You could try to implement the functionality yourself by recording the steps you used to create the canvas in the first place, and re-creating it with or without the relevant image.

Comment: so the solution is to redraw the whole canvas again?

Comment: Yes - I would say so.  Unless you can figure out how to just redraw the bit behind the image you want to remove.  But either way it will be up to you to track the elements on the canvas.

Comment: @jagguy - look at http://kineticjs.com/ and see if it has the functionality to do what you want.  I've only looked at it briefly, and bookmarked it for future use.

Comment: KIneticjs is something i will look at but for right now it wont help with this problem. I dont think these methods can help either getImageData putImageData method

Comment: Another possibility is to layer canvases, just put them over each other using z-index, so have a background canvas and a foreground canvas.